# CodeIgniter: Trailing Slash

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, php

In my CI app, I have the following controller:

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/frontend/login/
```

In this controller (the login controller), I have a method called `submit()`. The association view file for this controller has a form with `action='submit/'`. The idea is when the form submits, it goes to `http://localhost/myapp/index.php/frontend/login/` -- and it does as long as the URL has a trailing slash.

However, if the URL is like this (no trailing slash):

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/frontend/login
```

and I submit the form, I am redirected to the following instead:

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/frontend/submit/
```

This results in a 404 since I don't have a `submit` controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an absolute URL in the action

```
action="/myapp/index.php/frontend/submit/"
```

Comment: Is there any way to make form helper add trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

are you using CI's form helper?

```
//autoload/controller:
$this->load->helper('form');
// in your view:
<?php echo form_open('login/submit'); ?>
```

and when you have a "frontend" - how is that set up - just a folder within the controller directory?

the URL shouldn't have any effect on the outcome.

you may need

`<?php echo form_open('frontend/login/submit'); ?>`

but i don't think so
ie

```
controllers/
   |-frontend
       |-front_end_controller.php
```

Comment: 1.) no, I am not using CI form helper, and 2.) "frontend" is just a folder within the controller directory. Any idea what might be wrong?